# q implies q? What is the outcome?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

A beginner question, but one that is not covered in my book.

What happens when you have:

$$
q\implies q 
$$

Again I have had this come up sometimes, but my book never explains it. 
I'm sure it's something simple, but if someone could explain it clearly, that would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "what happens when"? Is that a question with mathematical content?

Comment: $q\implies q$ is always true.

Comment: Yes, I'm proving a tautology, and this comes up when I distribute.

Comment: Then you seem to have reached what you want. It's the logical equivalent of $1=1$.

Answer (score 1):

q always implies q so it is a tautology

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. I was confused as my book kept putting it off, but since I'm new to logical math, wanted to check as I was curious.

Answer (score 1):

A tautology is a formula which is true for every possibility, so when you get to

$$q\implies q$$

you have such a formula. Aside from just stating the obvious that a statement implies itself, we can argue logically that $q$ is either $T$ or $F$ which yields two scenarios:

$$T\implies T$$
$$F\implies F$$

which both evaluate to $T$. Since these are the only possibilities for $q\implies q$, such a statement will be $T$ for any statement $q$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check this with a small truth table. You have $1$ variable so therefore $2^1=2$ rows. The only possibilities are $p=T$ and $p=F$, so substituting

$$T \implies T$$

$$F \implies F$$

confirms that $p \implies p$ is indeed a tautology, since both of the above expressions evaluate to $T$.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the truth table for p => q?

p | q | p=>q

T | T | T

T | F | F

F | T | T

F | F | T

so of course, from the truth table, T=>T is T, and F=>F is T, so p=>p is always T

Answer (score 1):

If you're using boolean algebra, you can always get rid of implications systematically:

> $p \to q \equiv \neg p \lor q$.

Do the same with $q \to q$ and you will get an obvious tautology.